# $.get and setTimeout combination not working in IE

Tags: jquery

I have to execute particular code every 1 minute, I have coded like this. Below code is working in all browsers except in IE.
Issue is: ../common/ajaxpage.aspx is hitting very first time,from the next time is not hitting but timedcount is calling for every 1 minute and variable "data" returns "not elapsed" every time even though ajaxpage.aspx is not called.

```
var gt_t;
$(document).ready(function () {
    gt_t = setTimeout('timedCount()', 60000);
    OnSaveBtnFix();
    OnStart();
    alert(gt_t);
});

    function timedCount() {
        alert("timed count started");
        $.get('../common/AjaxPage.aspx', { action: 'sessionexp', TypeID: 'ClientID' }, function (data) {
            alert(data);
            if (data == "Elapsed") {
                dispalySessionPopup();
                gt_t = setTimeout('timedCount()', 60000);
            }
            else if (data == "null") {
                hidePopup('popupMsg');
                document.location.href = "../Index.aspx?logout=y";
            }
            else {                   
                gt_t = setTimeout('timedCount()', 60000);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: What do you see in the alert "alert(data)"?

Comment: Have you tried replacing `'timedCount()'` with just `timedCount` (no brackets and no quotes)?

Comment: Please don't pass strings to `setTimeout` (it uses `eval`), pass functions.  `gt_t = setTimeout(timedCount, 60000);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE is probably caching your request. You can convert your `$.get` call into a [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax) call and use the `cache` option. jQuery will add a timestamp to the end of the request, forcing the browser to make a fresh request:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '../common/AjaxPage.aspx',
    data: { action: 'sessionexp', TypeID: 'ClientID' },
    cache: false, // no caching
    success: function (data) { .... }
});
```

As a side note, it is considered a best-practice to use the version of `setTimeout` that takes a function reference, not a string. In other words:

```
gt_t = setTimeout('timedCount()', 60000);
```

could/should be rewritten:

```
gt_t = setTimeout(timedCount, 60000);
```